# What is character that equivalent to 00000000 in bytes?

Tags: java, character-encoding, binary, null, byte

I need to append character that 00000000 in byte in String builder.
I need to put it into String Array and and read it again later.
Example :

```
StringBuilder sBfNumRow = new StringBuilder();
sBfNumRow.append(""); //add char that 00000000 in byte
stObj [c] = sBfNumRow.toString(); // put into String array 
stObj [c] .getBytes // read it again later.
```

Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: Use sBfNumRow.append('\u0000');

Answer (score 1):

A *char* and *int* can be casted to each other so use that technique.

To illustrate.

```
int a = 0;
char zero = a;
```

Or use 0 direct without '0'

```
char zero = 0;
```

And in your code it would be.

```
BfNumRow.append((char) 0); //add char that 00000000 in byte
```

Edit: New answer provided thoughts to improve my answer

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
BfNumRow.append((char) 0);
```

if you want specifically use the char type. This

```
BfNumRow.append(0);
```

will use `StringBuilder.append(int)`.